# How do I get Protractor's $ to be defined properly when creating a browser through require('selenium-webdriver').Builder?

Tags: protractor

I'm creating a browser like this:

```
let seleniumWebdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
let Builder = seleniumWebdriver.Builder;
let Capabilities = seleniumWebdriver.Capabilities;

const chromeCapabilities = Capabilities.chrome();
chromeCapabilities.set('chromeOptions', {args: [
    // '--headless', 
    // '--window-size=1920,1080'
]});

function createBrowser() {
    let browser =  new Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .withCapabilities(chromeCapabilities)
        .build();

    return browser;
}

let browser = createBrowser();
```

Later I have this:

```
$('#userName');
```

`$` is undefined.  How do I get Protractor's `$` to be defined properly when creating a browser like that?

I tried:

```
$ = require('protractor').$
```

But then I get `$ is not a function`.

Comment: Protractor creates global objects for `browser`, `element`, `ExpectedConditions`, `$`, and `$$`. These global objects are tied to the browser instance from selenium-webdriver. Protractor automatically creates this browser session for you when launching a Protractor test. Why not do it that way? But in reference to your question, doing this is probably going to problematic. Also, Protractor is launched via a configuration file and command line, which is why `$` does not exist.

Comment: @cnishina "Why not do it that way?" All the code in my question existed before I started working on this.  I generally try to make the smallest change possible, avoiding refactoring when possible.  Thanks for the comment, though!

Comment: Maybe more context. Are you launching this with Protractor? How is the above launched?